# Is there a way to force Show to use a Datagrid?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am looking for a way to allow Show to be able to use a Datagrid on the show page. I want to be able to click on the show button and when the show page appears, I want to be able to take data and make another grid using Datagrid or something similar. Any Ideas how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems show page take 1 record and render its. on show page you can place related records with current. for example `news` can related with one `project` and one `project` has many `news`. code below get from api all related `news` and render its as a table. hope it helps you

```
export const ProjectShow = ({ ...props }) => (
  <Show title={<ProjectTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout>
      <ReferenceManyField label="News" reference="news" target="project_id">
          <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="title" />
            <DateField source="created_at" showTime />
            <DateField source="updated_at" showTime />
            <EditButton />
          </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceManyField>
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

don't remember place in App.js line:

```
<Resource name="projects"  ...another actions... show={ProjectShow} />
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to be exactly what I am looking for!